# How to flatten the bottom of a skewed container?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a container transformed with `transform: skew(0deg, -3deg )translateY(-6vh)`, but I'm using it for a footer, so I want it to be completely flat at the bottom part. How can I acheive it without covering it up with another container with the same background colour? (I don't want things to mess up the responsiveness).

Comment: Please post your code. We have no idea what your HTML or CSS looks like. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I would use the `::before` psuedo element. I couldn't figure out how to get the `::before` element to go under the main one, so you lose a little space, but it's not too bad.</s>

Using `::before` horribly failed. Plus, there is some oddities with using transform which can be seen if you just put a background color on the element and use a sufficiently wide screen.

So, rather than fight with that, I would just use an SVG to give you that slant you want. There was an odd space between the `svg` and `div`, so I used positioning to get around that.

You can play with the values to get the slant how you like, but be advised that it will vary based on the screen width.

```css
#footer {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  fill: green;
  max-height: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

#footerContent {
  margin-top:49px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 20" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="0,20 100,20 100,0" />
  </svg>
  <div id="footerContent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I meant and it seems this is the right direction. Mb someone knows how to cover the space left.

Comment: Well that's fun. It looked perfect in the editor. I'll try to mess with it some more in a bit.

Comment: @user11569827, see my edit. I used a different way to do it.